# What does the word $ \ \text{affine} \ $ impose in mathematics?

Tags: terminology, affine-varieties

What does the word $ \ \text{affine} \ $ impose in mathematics?

I want to understand it.

Like- $\text{affine space,  affine algebraic curve, affine plane}$ etc.

For example affine space is a generalisation of euclidean space with fixed origin and obtained by translation of a vector space $V$.

But still my question is-

What does the word $ \ \text{affine} \ $ impose in mathematics?

Can someone explain it please?

Comment: A plane in $\mathbb R^3$ going through the origin is a vector subspace of $\Bbb R^3$; if you translate that plane so it’s no longer containing the origin, then it’s affine

Comment: Traditionally, affine geometry, only used the vector space structure, as opposed to metric structure  (metric geometry) of points at infinity (projective geometry).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, so what does mean by $affine \ \ algebraic \ \ plane \ \ curve$?

Comment: It means an algebraic plane curve (i.e. a curve that is the solution set to some polynomial equation in two variables, like $x^2+y^2 = 1$) that isn't projective (i.e. we are not considering points that are infinitely far away).

Comment: @Arthur, thank you very much. I got it

Comment: Please don't use math mode for emphasis, it looks terrible. You can use single and double asterisks to get *italics* and **bold**.

Comment: @HansLundmark, ok I will remember it next time